# Slack: how does one go about providing the 'box/dropbox/google' like integration?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Slack offers Box/DropBox/Google integrations, specifically the ability to add (pick via a dialog) a file to Slack from one of these offerings.

I have tried my best look up the different sort of integration possibilities but cannot find any documentation that I can leverage to build my own (to another product).

How does one go about providing a similar integration for his product?

Comment: see also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425499/how-to-integrate-with-slack-similar-to-how-google-drive-did/48429418#48429418

Answer (score 0):

The reason you do not find anything on how to create integrate products similar to Google Drive and Dropbox in the official API documentation is that those are custom solutions created in collaboration between Slack and vendors like Google. If you want something similar for your product I would advise you to contact the Slack business team for details.

However, there is one feature in the API that allows you to create some of the functionality:

- [Slack app unfurling](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-link-unfurling#slack_app_unfurling): Automatically add custom attachments whenever a user posts a message which contains a URL to your product. Those can include preview images and text of your product.

Comment: thanks @Erik - I was afraid that was going to be the answer (custom integration). Looks like contacting them directly might be best at this point.